# Remove relative Layout margin with Screen in android

Tags: android

How I can Remove relative Layout margin with Screen ?

[look like This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9ulL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your margin from the RelativeLayout so it kind of looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
```